# Magento: Setting page template for store category

Tags: magento

I am trying to set the page template for my store. I have managed to customize pages in the store using local.xml, like this:

```
<page_one_column>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>custom/page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </page_one_column>

     <page_two_columns_left>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>custom/page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </page_two_columns_left>

    <page_two_columns_right>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>custom/page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </page_two_columns_right>

    <page_three_columns>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>custom/page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </page_three_columns>
```

Works fine on CMS pages. The store, however, still uses the template in template/page/2columns-left.phtml.

I have tried setting custom layout changes for the root category in the admin panel, with children inheriting from their parent, to no avail.

I have no idea where else I could have to set the page template.

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Comment: if you want to set template for every page of your store try the `default` handle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the example of setting the default template for complete website:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

or just for catalog:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_category_default>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>
</layout>
```

Comment: Is that the only way of achieving this? Can you not set the template specifically for store pages?

Comment: If I set it for the whole site, is it still possible to override for CMS pages via the admin?

Comment: Sure. Layout updates from admin have highest priorities.